# Finding efficiently if a triangle shape is formed between known coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm, performance

I have `n` points moving in a 2d plane and they are linked with a line. I need to know if a group of 3 points is forming a triangle. The link lines have a max length.

Actually my code iterates through all points one by one.
For each point `p1`, I take all links for `p1`, I iterate taking two links (i, i+1).
For those links, I find `p2` and `p3` (the link edge different from `p1`)
Having `p1`, `p2` and `p3` I check if `p2` and `p3` are linked.
If they are, I've found a triangle.

This solution is really heavy when there are a lot of triangles on the plane.

Do someone knows a better solution?

You can find a code sample here:

```js
const a = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const b = { x: 0, y: 50 };
const c = { x: 43, y: 25 };

const l1 = { edges: [a, b] };
const l2 = { edges: [a, c] };
const l3 = { edges: [b, c] };

const ls = [l1, l2, l3];
const al = ls.filter((l) => l.edges.includes(a));

for (let i = 0; i < al.length - 1; i++) {
  const fl = al[i];
  const sl = al[i + 1];
  const ai1 = fl.edges.indexOf(a);
  const b1 = fl.edges[(ai1 + 1) % 2];
  const ai2 = sl.edges.indexOf(a);
  const c1 = sl.edges[(ai2 + 1) % 2];

  // how do I find efficiently tl?
  const tl = ls.filter((l) => l.edges.includes(b1) && l.edges.includes(c1));

  if (fl && sl && tl) {
    console.log([a, b1, c1]);
  }
}
```

CodePen with the same code: https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/YzqQmXz

It's simplified code, but the structure is almost identical, points have coordinates, links have `edges` array with the points forming the link.

**An important note**:

I need to save the links and triangles because I need to know if each of them should be visible or not and it's a condition valid for all the object lifespan, I cannot recreate them for each animation frame.

If you want to see the real code you can find it here:

https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/tree/dev/core/main/src/Interactions/Particles

*Linker.ts* and *Triangler.ts* are the file creating links and triangles,

https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/blob/dev/core/main/src/Core/Canvas.ts

This file instead draws them and checks if what is drawing is still valid. (`drawLinks` and `drawLinkTriangles`  methods)

Comment: As I understand it, what you need to check in practice is whether the 3 points are collinear or not, correct? Because that way you guarantee that the 3 points form a triangle

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you mean